# Jmeter extracting response multiple id from array

Tags: jmeter

I am traying the extract the term-id- id value -200000000326 from the below response. controlled-term can have multiple term-id,  I have tried with Json extractor $..controlled-term.[[term-id]].[id]  and [Thursday 12:22 PM] G, Shwetha C
$..term-id[id]
but this is returning null. can you please help

```
enter code here:
{
"controlled-terms": {
    "controlled-term": [
        {
            "term-id": {
                "id": "200000000326"
            },
            "term-names": {
                "term-name": [
                    {
                        "lang": "en",
                        "name": "All"
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}}
```

Comment: I guess you have multiple `term-id` but any specific  value with `200000000326` present in the JSON or this is the first element, you need to explain on the basis of this can write the proper extractor.

Answer (score 0):

For particular that JSON you provided the relevant [JSONPath](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath) query would be something like:

```
$.controlled-term.*.term-id.id
```

[image]

If you need to extract particular ID which is related to some other attribute value - you will have to provide the full JSON response and specify the data relationships.

I would also recommend considering switching to [JSON JMESPath Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_JMESPath_Extractor) mainly because it has [official specification](https://jmespath.org/specification.html) (JSONPath implementations are lacking it so query which works for one implementation may fail for another). Moreover JMESPath language is more powerful and provides a lot of [functions and operators](https://jmespath.org/tutorial.html) which can make your life easier. More information: [The JMeter JSON JMESPath Extractor and Assertion: A Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/the-jmeter-json-jmespath-extractor-andassertion-a-guide)